# How to avoid generating empty tests results with "dotnet test"?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, .net-core, xunit, xunit.net

As part of my Build pipeline, I run Unit and Integration tests

For running Unit tests, I have the following line (note the filter for Unit at the end)

```
dotnet test -c Release -r linux-x64 --no-restore --no-build --verbosity minimal --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage" --settings ./coverlet.runsettings --results-directory "./artifacts/test-results" --logger "console;verbosity=normal;" --logger "trx;verbosity=normal;logfileprefix=unit;" --filter "Category=Unit"
```

For running Intregration tests, I have the following line (note the filter for Integration at the end)

```
dotnet test -c Release --no-restore --verbosity minimal --results-directory "./artifacts/test-results" --logger "console;verbosity=normal;" --logger "trx;verbosity=normal;logfileprefix=integration;" --filter "Category=Integration"
```

I am running these lines in a Github workflow which at the end generates a test report based on the test files produced.

The "dotnet test" command is producing one test file per project in my solution regardless of if there were tests in it that matched the given filter.

Therefore, the end result is:
[image]

I have 6 Test projects but not all of them have Unit or Integration tests. However, 6 tests result files are generated for Unit test and 6 more for Integration tests.

Is there a way to only generate a test result file if there were actual tests running in the project?

Comment: Have you fixed that? Looking for this solution too but so far no success.